# Query takes forever to output info - tips on optimization

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a query that works awesomely - but - it takes about 10 minutes to load up.  Which is insane. And I would like for it to run faster than it currently does now.

I was wondering if there were any tips I could take to optimize my query to make it run faster?

```
select DISTINCT
    c.PaperID, 
    cdd.CodesF, 
    c.PageCount,  
    prr.projectname,  
    u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname as Name,
    ett.EventName, 
    cast(c.AssignedDate as DATE) [AssignedDate],
    cast(ev.EventCompletionDate as DATE) [CompletionDate],
    ar.ResultDescription,
    a.Editor
from tbl_Papers c
    left outer join (select cd.PaperId, count(*) as CodesF 
                     from tbl_PaperCodes cd group by cd.PaperId) cdd 
        on cdd.PaperId = c.PaperId
    left outer join 
        (SELECT 
            wfce.PaperEventActionNum,
            c.PaperId,
            CONVERT(varchar,wfce.ActionDate,101) CompletionDate,
            pr.ProjectName,
            wfce.ActionUserId,
            u.firstname+' '+u.lastname [Editor]
        FROM 
            dbo.tbl_WFPaperEventActions wfce
            INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Papers c ON wfce.PaperId = c.PaperId
            INNER JOIN tbl_Providers p ON p.ProviderID = c.ProviderID
            INNER JOIN tbl_Sites s ON s.SiteID = p.SiteID
            INNER JOIN tbl_Projects pr ON s.ProjectId=pr.ProjectId
            INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON wfce.ActionUserId=u.UserId
        WHERE
            wfce.EventId = 204 
            AND c.Papersource =0
        GROUP BY
            wfce.PaperEventActionNum,
            c.PaperId,
            CONVERT(varchar,wfce.ActionDate,101),
            pr.ProjectName,
            wfce.ActionUserId,
            u.firstname+' '+u.lastname
        )a ON a.PaperId=c.PaperId,
    tbl_Providers p, tbl_Sites s, 
    tbl_Projects prr, tbl_WFPaperEvents ev, 
    tbl_Users u, tbl_WFPaperEventTypes ett, 
    tbl_WFPaperEventActions arr, tbl_WFPaperEventActionResults ar
where s.SiteId = p.SiteId
    and p.ProviderId = c.ProviderId
    and s.ProjectId = prr.ProjectId
    and ev.PaperId = c.PaperId
    and ev.EventCreateUserId = u.UserId
    and ev.EventCompletionDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
    and ev.EventCompletionDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
    and ev.EventStatusId = 3
    and ev.EventId in (201, 203)
    and c.Papersource =0--Offshore
    and ev.EventId=ett.EventID
    and arr.PaperId=c.PaperId
    and arr.EventId=ev.EventId
    and arr.EventId=ar.EventID
    and arr.ActionResultId=ar.ResultID
    and arr.ActionResultId in (1,2,3,4)
order by paperid, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide the schema for the tables?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan or identify any missing database indexes?

Comment: The second word! It's a performance killer. See Why I hate DISTINCT  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx

Comment: You are using a mix of joins and older 'where clause' join syntax...pick one or the other, not both (no functiuonality change really...it's just painful to try to figure out what you're joining). ETT is a complete cross join. Your use of 'distinct' should be avoided (it's likely what is 'fixing' your cross joins). After that...we need to see explain plan to see how well your indexes are used, and also helpful to get the table create statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-look carefully at every piece of this query and ask yourself, is that needed?

Take the subquery with alias a.

It joins 6 tables, but if you trace up to your final select clause only [Editor] is supplied from that alias. So do you need 6 tables to arrive at editor? No you don't in fact you only need 2 `tbl_WFPaperEventActions` and `tbl_Users`. Furthermore, this subquery is grouping by 6 items including a date, but 3 of those items are not used anywhere else in the overall query - so why go include these in the grouping? This allows us to drop 3 of the joined tables.

Of the remaining 3 grouping items a further 1 can be substituted to avoid the join between `tbl_WFPaperEventActions` and `tbl_Papers` because the join condition is "wfce.PaperId = c.PaperId", all we need then is to group by `wfce.PaperId` instead of `c.PaperId`

Finally we are then interested in the field `wfce.PaperEventActionNum` this is supplied by the subquery but isn't used in the larger query? Why provide that field is it isn't used? Well it turns out that it should be used to complete a join. The subquery aliased as a needs joining into the outer query on both `PaperEventActionNum` and `PaperId`. This by the way also requires that the whole subquery needs to be pushed down the joining structure to comply with ANSI join syntax rules.

**Never "mix" ANSI join syntax with joins done "the old fashioned way"**

This really is a recipe for a disaster.

Below I have "started" some amendments to your query, but I cannot really complete it as I have no way to test any part of it; and I don't know your data model at all.

Personally, I would re-start this query from scratch, starting lean and adding item by item to ensure it remains lean.

```
SELECT DISTINCT /* distinct isn't a good solution here */
      c.PaperID
    , cdd.CodesF
    , c.PageCount
    , prr.projectname
    , u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname       AS Name
    , ett.EventName
    , CAST(c.AssignedDate AS date)         [AssignedDate]
    , CAST(ev.EventCompletionDate AS date) [CompletionDate]
    , ar.ResultDescription
    , a.Editor
FROM tbl_Papers c
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ( -- can this be an inner join instead?
                  SELECT
                        cd.PaperId
                      , COUNT(*) AS CodesF
                  FROM tbl_PaperCodes cd
                  GROUP BY
                        cd.PaperId
            ) cdd
                  ON cdd.PaperId = c.PaperId
      INNER JOIN tbl_Providers p                  ON c.ProviderId = p.ProviderId
      INNER JOIN tbl_Sites s                      ON p.SiteId = s.SiteId
      INNER JOIN tbl_Projects prr                 ON s.ProjectId = prr.ProjectId
      INNER JOIN tbl_WFPaperEvents ev             ON c.PaperId = ev.PaperId
      INNER JOIN tbl_Users u                      ON ev.EventCreateUserId = u.UserId
      INNER JOIN tbl_WFPaperEventTypes ett        ON ev.EventId = ett.EventID
      INNER JOIN tbl_WFPaperEventActions arr      ON c.PaperId = arr.PaperId
                                                            AND ev.EventId = arr.EventId
      INNER JOIN tbl_WFPaperEventActionResults ar ON arr.EventId = ar.EventID
                                                            AND arr.ActionResultId = ar.ResultID
                                                            AND arr.ActionResultId IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        wfce.PaperEventActionNum
                      , wfce.PaperId
                      --, c.PaperId
                      --, CONVERT(varchar, wfce.ActionDate, 101) CompletionDate -- cast to date here
                      --, pr.ProjectName
                      --, wfce.ActionUserId
                      , u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname         [Editor]
                  FROM dbo.tbl_WFPaperEventActions wfce
                        --INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Papers c  ON wfce.PaperId = c.PaperId
                        --INNER JOIN tbl_Providers p   ON p.ProviderID = c.ProviderID
                        --INNER JOIN tbl_Sites s       ON s.SiteID = p.SiteID
                        --INNER JOIN tbl_Projects pr   ON s.ProjectId = pr.ProjectId
tbl_Users                        INNER JOIN  u       ON wfce.ActionUserId = u.UserId
                  WHERE wfce.EventId = 204
                        AND c.Papersource = 0
                  GROUP BY
                        wfce.PaperEventActionNum
                      , wfce.PaperId
                      --, c.PaperId
                      --, CONVERT(varchar, wfce.ActionDate, 101)
                      --, pr.ProjectName
                      --, wfce.ActionUserId
                      , u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname
            ) a
                  ON c.PaperId = a.PaperId AND arr.PaperEventActionNum = a.PaperEventActionNum



WHERE ev.EventCompletionDate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0)
      AND ev.EventCompletionDate < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
      AND ev.EventStatusId = 3
      AND ev.EventId IN (201, 203)
      AND c.Papersource = 0--Offshore


ORDER BY
      paperid, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName
```

---

I really do hate DISTINCT. It is nasty. It does not solve problems, it just hides them; AND slows down everything to do the hiding.

Use distinct in inverse proportion to query complexity:

- if a query is really simple you can use distinct
- If a query is complex do **not** use distinct

Comment: OMG - You're so right! I just removed Distinct (and only distinct) - just to see what kind of impact it would have and literally of the 8-10 minutes it previous took to load it only took 1 minute! That is absolutely insane!

Comment: There you go. This is not an uncommon story. But you have a lot of unwanted repetition in the results probably. Instead of trying for a quick fix at the top of the query, look deeper. The way to make it faster is probably inside the from clause. I was serious however about re-starting, it could be easier to build-up but this time watch the effect on the number of rows as you add each table. Whichever way you tackle it: best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check how many of fields on which you have `join`, `where` and `group by` clauses, have indexes. Every non-indexed field can negatively affect performance.
2. Calculated fields in GROUP BY are probably a pain, as well as DISTINCT (especially if they are not indexed). E.g. grouping on something like `u.ID` instead of `u.firstname+' '+u.lastname` or `pr.ProjectId` i/o `pr.ProjectName` should make things faster (you can sort the output according to the other criteria if needed).
3. Do you really need `left join` where you use it? I.e. do you want to keep the tables from the other side of the join even when there is no match on the other side? If not, replace it with `inner join`.
4. Various small improvements here, e.g.:

(assuming Papersource and EventId are indexes):

```
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_WFPaperEventActions WHERE EventId = 204) wfce
        INNER JOIN
           (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Papers WHERE Papersource = 0) c 
           ON wfce.PaperId = c.PaperId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Providers p ON p.ProviderID = c.ProviderID
        INNER JOIN tbl_Sites s ON s.SiteID = p.SiteID
        INNER JOIN tbl_Projects pr ON s.ProjectId=pr.ProjectId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON wfce.ActionUserId=u.UserId
```

instead of

```
    FROM 
        dbo.tbl_WFPaperEventActions wfce
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_Papers c ON wfce.PaperId = c.PaperId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Providers p ON p.ProviderID = c.ProviderID
        INNER JOIN tbl_Sites s ON s.SiteID = p.SiteID
        INNER JOIN tbl_Projects pr ON s.ProjectId=pr.ProjectId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Users u ON wfce.ActionUserId=u.UserId
    WHERE
        wfce.EventId = 204 
        AND c.Papersource =0
```

or (if I understood the idea correctly):

```
and ev.EventCompletionDate BETWEEN (
    dateadd(day, -1, GETDATE()) and dateadd(ns, -1, GETDATE())
```

instead of:

```
and ev.EventCompletionDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
and ev.EventCompletionDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

In general: ask yourself what exactly you want to achieve with this query, which parts of the data are relevant for it, how many of your source tables can be replaced with snippets from them (this can make JOINs work faster), and try to be consistent regarding the usage of JOIN and WHERE clauses.

Comment: actually the one thing that was done well was the date range; what you have proposed for that is just wrong I'm afraid. dateadd(ns,-1,getdate()) is affected by rounding and you will surprised to learn it just doesn't work. between sucks for date ranges, read this https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: oh, and getdate() carries time of day, so your proposed date range isn't the equivalent of the original which employs `dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)` that sets time to midnight.

Comment: ah ok, havent realized that. one BETWEEN clause should usually still be better than two separate clauses

Comment: `between` is translated into 2 separate operators, it has zero advantage that way, it is just a syntactic shortcut. It equates to (is evaluated as) `[field] >= value and [field] <= value`. Seriously between cannot to be trusted for date ranges. Please read Aaron Bertand's blog on this if you won't believe me.

Comment: Will do, thanks. I knew people who believed otherwise :) Or may be it's different for MySQL and for T-SQL.

Comment: No difference: `between` is consistent across rdbms implementations. The specifics of date/time precision does alter, but the wrongness of using between for date ranges is very consistent.